# Whatsapp delivered message a deleted message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, delete

I deleted a Whatsapp message that I sent while my phone was offline and the clock sign was there , I did not see the single tick sign (meaning that the message supposedly did not leave my phone). Still the message was delivered to the recipient's phone after I got back online. Why is that? what can I do to stop this in the future? What can I  do to stop a message from going to a group? I can not block the group nor can I leave it.